is there a way to modify a text written in drawtext with the pdf-lib library
Does anyone know if there is a way to modify a text written in drawtext with the pdf-lib library or another library that I can use in script apps?
I wrote this code:
setTimeout = (func, sleep) => (Utilities.sleep(sleep),func())
async function modifyPdf() {
  //async
  const pdfData = new Uint8Array(DriveApp.getFileById("1Zy4Fbq__ubjX0NLs7J5WPGj7JlV_8-KJ").getBlob().getBytes());
 
  const { PDFDocument, StandardFonts, PDFName, PDFRawStream, decodePDFRawStream, arrayAsString, rgb, degrees} = PDFLib;

  const pdfDoc = await PDFDocument.load(pdfData);
  const helveticaFont = await pdfDoc.embedFont(StandardFonts.Helvetica);

  const pages = pdfDoc.getPages();
  const firstPage = pages[0];
  const { width, height } = firstPage.getSize();
  //firstPage.drawText(`This text was added with JavaScript\n\n${' '.repeat(10)}(Google Apps script)!`, {
 firstPage.drawText(`This text was added with JavaScript`, {
    x: 10,
    y: height - 10,
    size: 20,
    font: helveticaFont,
    color: rgb(0.95, 0.1, 0.1)
    //rotate: degrees(20),
    //opacity: 0.5,
  });

  const pdfBytes = await pdfDoc.save();
  Drive.Files.update(
    {
      title: "newpdf from apps script v22",
      mimeType: "application/pdf"
    },
    "1Zy4Fbq__ubjX0NLs7J5WPGj7JlV_8-KJ",
    Utilities.newBlob(pdfBytes)
  )

the problem is that if I run it the first time it will write on the PDF "this text was added..." but if I run it a second time, it will write over it... I would like to be able to change the text so Should we be able to ensure that it replaces it?
Is there a way via this library or another, or another way to achieve this?
for the moment it overlaps every time


pdf-lib can remove and edit the content of text fields (see PDFTextField.setText), but it does not provide APIs for removing or editing text on a page outside of a form field. This is also a difficult feature to implement, but is within the scope of pdf-lib and may be added in the future. See #93, #137, #177, #329, and #380.


pdf-lib does not currently support encrypted documents. You should not use pdf-lib with encrypted documents.

PDF-Lib has not been updated since Nov 12, 2021.
Thus there is no current way for you to edit an existing PDF unless it is decrypted and you only use text fields (annotation).
